# How can I help Azure Network Security Group rules recognize Service Tags for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am attempting to setup inbound Network Security Group rules to permit controlled access from Azure DevOps Pipelines to Azure a public Azure vnet which interfaces with a private Azure vnet containing Azure Container Instances which are running Sonarqube. I've crafted this according to the Azure documents [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview).

The NSG rule for the inbound traffic from Azure DevOps is leveraging Service Tags, specifically the ‘AzureDevOps’ service tag. My ARM template currently contains these two NSG rules:

```
{
             "name": "inbound-devops-rule",
             "properties": {
             "description": "Inbound Azure DevOps",
             "protocol": "*",
             "sourcePortRange": "*",
             "destinationPortRange": "*",
             "sourceAddressPrefix": "AzureDevOps",
             "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
             "access": "Allow",
             "priority": 100,
             "direction": "Inbound"
                 }
             },
             {
             "name": "InboundRequiredGatewayPorts",
             "properties": {
             "description": "Inbound AZ admin",
             "protocol": "TCP",
             "sourcePortRange": "*",
             "destinationPortRange": "65200-65535",
             "sourceAddressPrefix": "GatewayManager",
             "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
             "access": "Allow",
             "priority": 115,
             "direction": "Inbound"
                 }
             },
```

Currently, this does not permit traffic through the NSG rules and into the vnets. The only thing I’ve been able to do to resolve this in my testing has been to create a fully open rule allowing all traffic from all sources in my NSG…obviously not an ideal scenario from a security perspective. I have combed through the documents and attempted dozens of different configurations up to this point, and nothing but open/unprotected NSG configuration has allowed Azure DevOps traffic.

The simple error I am currently getting when attempting to connect to my containerized Azure Sonarqube resources from the Azure DevOps pipelines is:

```
2022-12-02T19:46:46.7098999Z ##[section]Starting: SonarQubePrepare
 2022-12-02T19:46:46.7231846Z ==============================================================================
 2022-12-02T19:46:46.7232191Z Task         : Prepare Analysis Configuration
 2022-12-02T19:46:46.7232466Z Description  : Prepare SonarQube analysis configuration
 2022-12-02T19:46:46.7232684Z Version      : 5.8.0
 2022-12-02T19:46:46.7232868Z Author       : sonarsource
 2022-12-02T19:46:46.7233232Z Help         : Version: 5.8.0. [More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
 2022-12-02T19:46:46.7233633Z ==============================================================================
 2022-12-02T19:47:08.4683602Z ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"errno":"ETIMEDOUT","code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"<REDACTED>","port":80}
 2022-12-02T19:47:08.4811763Z ##[section]Finishing: SonarQubePrepare
```

Based on the rule sample above, is this properly configured to allow traffic from Azure DevOps using Service Tags? Can any additional guidance be provided for setting up NSG rules to allow traffic from my Azure DevOps pipelines to Azure containerized resources?

Comment: Hi, did you try creating thoses 2 policies via the portal or check if there are ok after arm creation?

Comment: These are initially being created via AZ CLI and fed in via a .json ARM config file. However, regardless of whether I create them manually or via AZ CLI/ARM, my Azure DevOps process are unable to connect through Service Tag enabled NSG rules.

Comment: Hi @DCaugs , have you got a chance to check my post? I am following up to make sure my suggestion works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps Microsoft-hosted agents are using the Service Tag **AzureCloud.region** instead of Azure DevOps, addressed here: [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking)

[image]

First check your DevOps organization region in DevOps UI.

[image]

Then check the region in this [Azure Geography](https://azure.microsoft.com/global-infrastructure/geographies/)

Pay attention to this: To obtain the complete list of possible IP ranges for your agent, you must use the IP ranges from all of the regions that are contained in your geography.

[image]

For your reference: if your DevOps organization locates in UK, you must add the service tag for both AzureCloud.uksouth and AzureCloud.ukwest to the NSG Inbound Security Rules to ensure the MS-hosted agents have access to the Azure Resources.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was the missing link. Thank you!